# how to use mysq transaction commit rollback in Lambda function using nodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, lambda, aws-lambda

Hi i want to use Mysql's beginTransactio or transactio commit rollback functionality in my Lambda(Node) function.
I tried basic structure of mysql package but seems its not working in lambda

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const con = mysql.createConnection(
        {
            host: "host",
            user: "user",
            password: "*****",
            database: "db"
        }
    );
    con.beginTransaction(
        function (err) {
            con.query(
                "query goes here",
                function (err, status) {
                    if (err) {
                        con.rollback();
                        con.end();
                        return err;
                    } else {
                        con.commit();
                        con.end();
                        return true;
                    }
                })
        });
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you share some more insights?

Comment: @Er_sherlockian there are no errors as such. just transactions are not happening as it suppose to. For example I have two insert queries and there is an error in second query so it should rollback first inserted record which is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the delayed answer.
just needed to specify beginTransaction without callback

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const con = mysql.createConnection(
        {
            host: "host",
            user: "user",
            password: "*****",
            database: "db"
        }
    );
    con.beginTransaction(); //here i was declaring standard callback function with err parameter
            con.query(
                "query goes here",
                function (err, status) {
                    if (err) {
                        con.rollback();
                        con.end();
                        return err;
                    } else {
                        con.commit();
                        con.end();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
}
```